# PowerApps - Unable to set SharePoint Person/People field to Current User

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, powerapps, peoplepicker

**I am uable to set a person field to the current user in a PowerApp.** I have followed the tutorial below but the dropdown control is not set to current user. This approach seems to be the general consensus on how to do this. I must be missing a step.

http://www.codeovereasy.com/2017/07/powerapps-set-sharepoint-person-field-to-current-user/

**OnVisible property of my screen:**

```
//Here I am setting the person field record to a variable 'myself' with current user values
Collect(Collection1, {Pressed: Button1.Pressed});
 UpdateContext({ 
  myself: { 
   '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
    Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(User().Email),   
    Department:"", 
    DisplayName:User().FullName,
    Email:User().Email, 
    JobTitle:".", 
    Picture:"."
  },
  manager: Office365Users.ManagerV2(Office365Users.MyProfile().Id).mail,
  varAlwaysTrueForTest: true})
```

**Default property of person field dropdown control:**

```
//This should show the current user in the dropdown control after the screen becomes visible
If(varAlwaysTrueForTest, myself, Parent.Default)
```

**Update property of person field DataCard:**

```
//DataCardValue6 is my person dropdown control
If(varAlwaysTrueForTest, myself, DataCardValue6.Selected)
```

**Result - should be populated with current user**

[image: blank person field]

Comment: Please leave a comment if you have an issue with my post. I cannot improve it if you down vote without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer in the post below. The root issue is the property that needs to be set on the dropdown control. It should be the **DefaultSelectedItems.** Also, the record being passed to the control only requires the `DisplayName` and `Claims` properties.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/How-to-set-a-defaul-value-for-a-person-fields-in-a-SharePoint/m-p/188290#M61575

**OnVisible event of screen**

```
UpdateContext({ myself: 
 { 
    Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(User().Email), 
    DisplayName:User().FullName 
 }
})
```

**DefaultSelectedItems**

```
If(varAlwaysTrueForTest, myself, Parent.Default)
```